# How to fix "Capturing 'block' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle"

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I am working on this code, which does some lengthy asyncronous operation on the net and when it finishes it  triggers a completion block where some test is executed and if a variable get a certain value another lengthy operation should start immediately:

```
-(void) performOperation
{

    void(^completionBlock) (id obj, NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request)= ^(id obj,NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request){


        int variable=0;

        // Do completion operation A
        //...
        //...

        // Do completion operation B                
        //Get the variable value

        if(variable>0){
            [self doLengthyAsynchronousOperationWithCompletionBlock: completionBlock];
        }

    };

//Perform the lenhgty operation with the above completionBlock
    [self doLengthyAsynchronousOperationWithCompletionBlock: completionBlock];

}

-(void) doLengthyAsynchronousOperationWithCompletionBlock: completionBlock
{
    //Do some lengthy asynchronous stuff
}
```

With this code I get this warning from the compiler:

```
WARNING: Block pointer variable 'completionBlock' is uninitialized when caputerd by the block
```

I changed:

```
void(^completionBlock) (id obj, NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request)= ^(id obj,NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request)
```

in:

```
__block void(^completionBlock) (id obj, NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request)= ^(id obj,NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request)
```

but I get this other warning:

```
WARNING 2: Capturing 'completionBlock' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Nicola

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761074/arc-blocks-and-retain-cycles)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> WARNING: Block pointer variable 'completionBlock' is uninitialized
>   when captured by the block

This happens because block variables initialized to a recursive block need `__block` storage.

- Variables within a block are copied unless declared with `__block`, in which case they are passed as reference.
- When a recursive block is assigned to a block variable, the creation happens before the assignment, and such creation triggers a variable copy. Given that the variable hasn't been assigned yet, the copied variable will be a bad value, and it will produce a crash when the block is ran.
- But if we add `__block`, the block will be created with a reference to the variable instead. Then the variable will be initialized to the created block, and the block will be ready to use.

> WARNING: Capturing 'completionBlock' strongly in this block is likely
>   to lead to a retain cycle

This happens because a block variable is a strong reference to the block, and the block is itself referencing the variable (because as we saw before, the variable has a `__block` so it is referenced instead copied).

So we need

- A weak reference to the strong variable inside the block.
- And a strong reference outside to prevent the block from being deallocated during the scope of the method where it is created.

```
    void(^ completionBlock) (id obj, NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request);
    void(^ __block __weak weakCompletionBlock) (id obj, NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request);
    weakCompletionBlock = completionBlock = ^(id obj,NSError *err, NSURLRequest *request){
        [self lengthyAsyncMethod:weakCompletionBlock];
    };
```

The name `doLengthyAsynchronousOperationWithCompletionBlock` suggests that the method may outlive the method scope where the block is created. Given that the compiler doesn't copy a block passed as an argument, it's responsibility of this method to copy this block. If we are using this block with block aware code (eg: `dispatch_async()`), this happens automatically.

Had we been assigning this block to an instance variable, we would need a `@property(copy)` and a weak reference to self inside the block, but this is not the case, so we just use self.

Comment: I tried something like this and it seem to work: I save the block in a copy property of the controller then I pass the property as completionBlock. Nicola

Comment: you don't need `__block` on `completionBlock` because it's never used in a block! in fact, it's never used anywhere

Comment: also, `self` is not what the OP's warning is about. We don't know whether `self` strongly references the block (the OP does not show us enough code to see that), so it is not safe to assume that it needs to be `__weak`

Comment: still, `completionBlock` is never used and should be removed. And the `__block` `on weakCompletionBlock` *is* necessary (so removing it is incorrect) since its value is not assigned by the time the block is created.

Comment: @newacct thanks for your comments, I still need to read more about blocks. However, I don't understand why completionBlock is not needed. It seems to me that it must be present to prevent deallocation of the block before lengthyAsyncMethod has a chance to copy it.

Comment: @Jano: nevermind, you're right. I forgot that `completionBlock` is used later to pass to `doLengthyAsynchronousOperationWithCompletionBlock:`