# NSMutableAttributedString strike-through with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)setStrokeLabel:(BOOL)strokeLabel
{
    _strokeLabel = strokeLabel;

    if (_strokeLabel) {
        _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(setStrokeThrough) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [self cancelStrokeThrough];
    }
}

- (void)setStrokeThrough
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= [attributedString length]; i++) {
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                 value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, i)];
        self.attributedText = attributedString;
    }
}

- (void)cancelStrokeThrough
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
    [attributedString removeAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])];
    self.attributedText = attributedString;

}
```

I want to animate `strike-through`, like todo done animation.
As I set timer for it, the timer only handle how to show the stoke through letter by letter??

Comment: This is not an animatable property.  The best you can do is setup a timer yourself and go letter by letter.

Comment: Thank you @borrrden, even though I set a NSTimer for it but the result is not obvious.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the result is not obvious"

Comment: I want it strike slowly letter by letter, _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(setStrokeThrough) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]; something has error?

Comment: That timer will not repeat, for one thing, but you should update your question with all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are two functions which do the job.**

```
    BOOL setStrokethrough(UILabel *label, NSRange range)
    {
        if (range.location >= [label.attributedText length])
            return FALSE;

        if (range.location + range.length > [label.attributedText length])
            range.length = [label.attributedText length] - range.location;

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];

        [attributedString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                                 value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                                 range:range];

        label.attributedText = attributedString;
        return TRUE;
    }

    -(void)animateSetStrokethroughDuration:(float)duration
    {
        __block float const stepDuration = 0.1;
        float steps = duration / stepDuration;
        __block NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, ceil((float)[self.label.attributedText length] / steps));

        void (^__block fn)();
        void (^__block __weak weakfn)();

        weakfn = fn = ^(){
            if (!setStrokethrough(self.label, range))
                return;
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, range.length);
            [self performBlock:weakfn afterDelay:stepDuration];
        };
        fn();
    }
```

**Notes**

1. To put a limit on animation time I animate by blocks of characters, rather than charater by character. The longer the string the longer the block of characters.
2. __block __weak business explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638751/how-to-fix-capturing-block-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a-reta)
3. self performBlock is an extension of NSObject by [Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html) and
   also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007023/blocks-instead-of-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay)
4. The code assumes you have self.label member defined